# Impossible to create my first bundle with terminal

Tags: symfony

I do hope that someone could help me to solve this strange problem.
I've just installed the latest version of Symfony 3.3 and when i use the create bundle generator command in terminal it return this error message and i can't access anymore to main web page of Symfony. I work with Mac OS X 10.11.6 :

Checking that the bundle is autoloaded
FAILED

> Enabling the bundle inside app/AppKernel.php
>     updated /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/app/AppKernel.php
>   OK
>   Importing the bundle's routes from the app/config/routing.yml file
>     updated /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/app/config/routing.yml
>   OK
>
> The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
>     You'll need to make the following changes manually.
>
> - Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
>     namespace in the "autoload" section:

Thank you in advance for your kindness.

Walter.

Answer (score 0):

The message clearly states what you should do. You need to manually register your new bundle namespace in autoload section in `composer.json` file.

By default this section should look similar to this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

Now you need to add similar line to that for `AppBundle`.

E.g.:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "ExampleNewBundle\\": "src/ExampleBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

I assume that your new bundle is placed under `src/ExampleBundle`, which is default path.

Then also run `composer install` or just `composer dump-autoload`, to let Composer generate your new autoloader classes.

Comment: Hi Jakub, thank you so much for your tip. I will try your settings and I keep you informed about the result. Have a nice week-end. Kind regards. Walter